# How to add LED effects to PCBs?

Tags: led, pcb

I don't mean LEDs for indication, debugging, etc. I mean LED effects like on the [MSI Z370 Motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z370-GAMING-PLUS.html), where entire sections of the board are illuminated by continuous strips of light. How is this accomplished?

Comment: "...entire sections of the board are illuminated by continuous strips of light." Just curious - do you have photos of the actual motherboard? As far as I can tell, the marketing material on the website you linked are renders.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://storage-asset.msi.com/global/picture/image/feature/mb/Z370/Z370GodlikeGaming/Z370-godlike-gaming-RGB.jpg)?

Comment: i looked at the web page that you linked .... all you need is red paint

Comment: I think he means the RED LED board with the diffused RED back light under the board reflecting off a diffused optically "flat" surface.in a dark room

Comment: no, i think that the OP is mistaking painted lines for `continuous strips of light` ..... another consumer dazzled by advertising gimmicks .... lol

Comment: Or maybe it's the dazzling back-glow fading in and out http://tinyurl.com/y2l5h3t4

Comment: @jsotola  lol Falstad is so easy, my brother-in-law Prof at U of T in EE power Systems was impressed by the user interface and ease of simulation.  http://tinyurl.com/yxebxnv2 when I showed him after dinner last nite.

Comment: Are you referring to the illuminated strip between the sound circuitry and the rest of the PCB, along the lower half of near the left edge?

Comment: @jsotola _"another consumer dazzled by advertising gimmicks .... lol"_ - You can dismiss it all you want, but the fact is, this is a real thing some motherboards have ([photograph](http://media.redgamingtech.com/rgt-website/2015/10/msi-z170-glowing-led.jpg)). I used to own one with such a light strip, so I can confirm its existence.

Comment: @marcelm, i do not doubt the existence of decorative illumination on a board ..... the problem is that the OP presented a board with red painted lines as an example one such product ..... basically,  the OP's question does not contain enough information

Comment: @marcelm, do you remember if the lights were attached to the underside of the motherboard? ....... fiberglass PCBs are fairly translucent ...... any gap in copper and in the silkscreen layer would pass light fairly easily

Comment: @Daniel, I actually own the motherboard I linked. It's light, not paint.

Comment: @jsotola, I actually own the motherboard I linked. It's light, not paint.

Comment: all of the thin diagonal lines are actually gaps in the silkscreen that allow the backlight to shine through?

Comment: The photo linked by @marcelm looks like there is copper plane separation, and the manufacturer is shining an LED through from the back of the PCB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually this is done with a small side-firing LED that shines into a light guide film to distribute the light.  Sometimes they etch small features so the light comes out at only certain places.

Here is an example of similar technology ([LINK](https://plastic-electronic.com/multiskin-circuit-carriers/)) :
[image]
The circuit carrier film can be a PCB.

EDIT:  Fun coincidence:  I was assembling a new embedded system this morning, and on power-up noticed the motherboard has this same feature:

[image]

It is a [Gigabyte GA-H270N-WIFI](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H270N-WIFI-rev-10#kf).

Comment: Please provide a link or citation to the original source of the image you included in your answer.

Comment: It is from a company that I have manufacture this kind of thing for me, and I didn't want to be accused of advertising.

Comment: You can downvote me all you want, however, this is precisely how we add LED effects to our PCBs.

Comment: I changed the image and link to a company I have no affiliation with.

Comment: Cool, but...is this what MSI is doing, or is their ad simply a gimmick?

Comment: I agree with other commenters that OP is probably mistaken about his example, but to answer their specific question, this is how it is done.

Comment: @evil: I don't think there is any problem with presenting something you have a commercial interest in provided that you declare it in the post. This should be especially true for an occasional mention by a high-rep user as it demonstrates that it's not the sole reason for a post. A mention in your user profile might be good too - and might help the business.

Comment: @evildemonic, I actually own the motherboard I linked. It's light, not paint. Are these light guides usually custom-made? Do you know of any sources of "cookie-cutter" light guides like this?

Comment: @BenS. These are done by the boardhouse that makes the PCBs and are fully custom.  Unfortunately not something you could have make sense in low volumes.  You might look into 'light pipes' to attempt something only slightly similar but much much cheaper.